# Getting the average number of Desktops per order -SQL

Tags: sql

Let's say that I have 4 tables

```
Order (OrderID, ComputerID, Quantity, Type_PC)
Computer (ComputerID, Model)
Desktop (ComputerID, specs, Cost)
Laptop (ComputerID, specs, Cost)
```

I am trying to get the average number of Desktops per order.

```
SELECT order.orderid, avg(order.quantity) AS AvgDesktopsSold
FROM computer, order
WHERE order.type_pc ="desktop" AND computer.computerid = order.computerid;
```

I have an error that says `Column "Desktop" not found`

Can you help me with this SQL problem?

Comment: use single quotes around 'desktop' instead of double quotes. The double quotes cause it to be interpreted as a column name.

Comment: `order` is a key sql word, I would highly suggest changing the table name to something else to help with the readability of your querys.

Comment: You can only have one type of PC per order?  That seems really wrong.  What if someone wants to order two laptops and two desktops?  You would have to create two orders.  And when you start selling notepads, you'll have to create a new table.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL standard regards double quotes as enclosing 'delimited identifiers', meaning that double quotes indicate that the name inside is a column or table name, or thereabouts.  You need to use single quotes around strings.

Many of the Unix-based DBMS are fairly flexible over strings in double quotes.  Clearly, the one you're using is not, or is not configured to be.

You also should avoid using the `FROM computer, order` notation.  You need to know it exists in case you read really old code, but you should always use explicit JOIN notation in your SQL.  So, if you need the join, you should be writing:

```
SELECT order.orderid, AVG(order.quantity) AS AvgDesktopsSold
  FROM computer
  JOIN order ON computer.computerid = order.computerid
 WHERE order.type_pc = 'desktop';
```

You should also be using a GROUP BY clause.  Any non-aggregate column should be in the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT order.orderid, AVG(order.quantity) AS AvgDesktopsSold
  FROM computer
  JOIN order ON computer.computerid = order.computerid
 WHERE order.type_pc = 'desktop'
 GROUP BY order.orderid;
```

However, as you aren't using any columns from the Computer table (let alone the Desktop or Laptop tables), you don't even need the JOIN:

```
SELECT orderid, AVG(quantity) AS AvgDesktopsSold
  FROM order
 WHERE type_pc = 'desktop'
 GROUP BY orderid;
```

Now, that will give you an answer for the 'average number of desktops for each order that is for desktops', but that average is also the quantity.  So, you really don't need the `orderid` in the select-list, or the GROUP BY clause after all:

```
SELECT AVG(quantity) AS AvgDesktopsSold
  FROM order
 WHERE type_pc = 'desktop';
```